# How to implement "Like/Dislike" on a Post like in Facebook/Instagram using Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, nosql

I am creating a social media app using flutter and firebase. Right now, the Like/Dislike button only acts as a counter. Basically, I still don't have any how to implement the feature the same as in Facebook/Instagram. Can anyone help me how to implement the feature? It would be much better if someone can provide a diagram on how this feature actually works.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you to keep a `likes` and `dislikes` field in the document. Create a subcollection within each post where you store the uids of users liking / disliking the post. Setup a cloud function which increases/decreases the `likes` or `dislikes` fields whenever someone likes/dislikes. To check if the current user has liked, just perform a basic query, checking if the current user's uid is present in the likes/dislikes subcollections, and display it in the UI accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Ok]

You can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/like_button) package to get the like animation.For more help, you can add code snippets to which I can reply

Comment: Storing likes and dislikes as an array is not very good, you'll eventually run into scalability issues. Rather, I'll suggest you to keep a document for each like and dislike, anyway you'll get charged for a write.

Comment: So lets say if you are making instagram like card or tiktok like design, so you will fetch every documents using streambuilder in like dislike collection and doing so will cause read write at every setstate. i guess he is learning for now so scalability is not an issue here @Arnoodles

Comment: No, not exactly, we can keep one counter variable which counts the overall likes in that same document where the post's data is present. And store the details/uids of people who liked jt in different documents( ths way, when we tap on details, then only we'll need to fetch thise docs)..and, we can setup a cloud func whch uodates that counter whenever someone likes/dislikes. To check that user has liked or not, we can just check if the current user's uid is present in yhe likes/dislikes.

Comment: So for every like or dislike you will read write for twice and to check if particular user liked or not you have to go check in like collection, just think the conditions and streams at widget level. He is learning so I guess this complexity doesn't matter

Comment: Yeah for beginners it makes sense